# how test a gRPC endpoint that returns com.google.type.Money

Tags: kotlin, postman, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I want manually test the bellow gRPC endpoint which returns com.google.type.Money. I am quite new to gRPC/proto world and I have manually tested them with BloomRPC. So far so good. But now there is a specific field type and BloomRPC is complaining with

```
Error while importing protos
no such Type or Enum 'google.type.Money'
```

It seems it can't parse google.type.Money. Any clue how I could test my gRPC endpoint manually?

proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

    package com.mycomp.adapters.grpc.test;
    
    import "google/api/annotations.proto";
    import "google/type/money.proto";
    
    service TestService {
    
      rpc GetTest (GetTestRequest) returns (Test) {
      }
    }
    
    message GetTestRequest{
        string id_cliente = 1;
    }
    
    message Test {
      string id_cliente = 1;
      google.type.Money test_money = 2;
    }
```

gRPC endpoint

```
import com.google.type.Money
...other imports

@Singleton
class TestEndpoint() : TestServiceGrpcKt.TestServiceCoroutineImplBase() {

    override suspend fun getTest(request: GetTestRequest): Test {

        val test = Test.newBuilder()

        ...
        
        test.testMoney = Money.newBuilder()
           .setCurrencyCode("USD")
           .setUnits(999)
           .build();

        return test.build()
    }
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    
    implementation ("com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.0.0")
}
```

Comment: See [this github issue](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc/issues/132) and maybe try adding an import path.

Comment: @cs95 I tried followed it by downloading the jar file from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.grpc/proto-google-common-protos/2.0.1 and imported it to BloomRPC but I don't see any difference. It is still same issue message. Basically, I clicked in "Import Paths" and added the path where the jar is located.  Do you know if I am missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The location to be added to "Import Paths" is expected to be a directory relative to which the path will be resolved (and **not** the path of protobuf file or the directory in which it is present).

Eg. If my extracted protobuf file's location is `/home/lorefnon/Workspace/sample-project/spi/build/extracted-include-protos/main/google/type/money.proto` then the import path to be added is `/home/lorefnon/Workspace/sample-project/spi/build/extracted-include-protos/main` relative to which the path `google/type/money.proto` can be resolved.